# BlueNRG_Stack_Initialization error 0x48 on BlueNRG1

Tags: c, sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluenrg

I have been having struggles while programming the Bluenrg1, more specifically when trying to start the BLE mode on it.

The method **BlueNRG_Stack_Initialization** is returning 0x48 which refers to `BLE_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY`. All this happened with the DK version 3.2.2 for the bluenrg1 and bluenrg2.

I could obtain the 3.2.1 version of the DK and it works well. After some research I found the value that cause the error, I'll post the solution for my own question to help anybody having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because of a change on the **Bluenrg1_stack.h** header located on the folder *../Bluetooth_LE/inc/* of the DK 3.2.2 **->**

Change `FIXED_BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES` from 6480 (DK 3.2.1) to 6536 (DK 3.2.2)
Change `VARIABLE_BUFFER_SIZE_PER_LINK_BYTES` from 336 (DK 3.2.1) to 344 (DK 3.2.2)

The `VARIABLE_BUFFER_SIZE_PER_LINK_BYTES` creates the error because it requires more memory allocation than the one created on the beacon configuration.

Just rever the value to the one on the DK 3.2.1 and it will run without an error.